# Error in dispatcher-servlet.xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am new to spring mvc frame work.I tried to do 2 helloworld web application but i failed to do so.The reason is that as given below(this error happens at dispatcher-servlet.xml page..here in the screenshot its name is welcome-servlet.xml,and not in web.xml)

Referenced file contains errors[the below url is my error] (http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd)

welcome-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="java4s" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean> 
</beans>
```

this is the error in both my projects.What is happening here?How  to resolve these errors?Why it came common in both my project?

```
   I change the version of all these to 2.5 and 3 and tested.But the same error shows.
```

I am using library files(not maven).Feeling totally confused what to do...

I added all those dependencies as specified in tutorial http://www.java4s.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-spring-mvc-3-2-hello-world-example-in-eclipse/(I rechecked it thoroughly,all jars are in my program and versions are correct as specified).

Nb:I know about latest spring mvc(4 versions) and due to limitations from my office i am not able to use it.[image]

Can anybody help me.any help will be highly appreciable(1 whole day wasted in this error)

Comment: Eclipse sometimes gets confused, ignore it if your application just runs. You also failed to tell what the error is...

Comment: M.Deinum:: i checked,my web application is not running(using apache tomcat8

Comment: Please share your web.xml file.

Comment: Whats the error that you are getting ?

Comment: Add DTD and Try. <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">.

Comment: Run it. Sometime eclipse giving error without reason. Just do clean build you will be fine.

Comment: @KSHiTiJ that is really bad advice, don't use the DTD use schemas instead. The DTD stuff is old, very old...

Comment: hey guys,i changed "spring-context-3.0.xsd" to 3.1 and now that error goes.I dont know is it the right way to fix it.

followed this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684673/spring-mongo-1-0-xsd-error