# Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.10.2.xsd'

Tags: java, xml, spring, mongodb, xsd

Running into this error when attempting to build project. I noticed a similar issue on this site with [spring-mongo-1.0.xsd error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684673/spring-mongo-1-0-xsd-error) but changing it to 1-1 and now 1-10.2 hasn't helped. Using the Spring reference guide (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.10.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.core)

Below is a portion of my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.10.2.xsd">

    <!-- Default bean name is 'mongo' -->
    <mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017"/>

</beans>
```

POM.xml:

```
    <!-- mongodb java driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Stack trace:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 49; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.10.2.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:99)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:392)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:306)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4160)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(XSDHandler.java:4151)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument1(XSDHandler.java:2493)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2191)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:576)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2446)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement
```

Comment: Do you have any stack trace?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy, yes. I've added it to the question now.

Comment: It could be a networking error, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729307/spring-schemalocation-fails-when-there-is-no-internet-connection

Comment: @minus, I'm able to build and run successfully removing the mongo schemas. I'm also able to hit the mongo xsd urls. It could be perhaps that I'm missing a key JAR file?